# A method using Boolean expression

Tags: c#, methods, boolean

The user has to pick 2 number to 1) Add 2) Subtract 3) Multiply 4) Divide 5) Quit.
The 2 number that the user entry can be 0-9, a decimal point, or minus sign, and anything else is a error.I need to create a method to check the user entry , by using a  true or false Boolean expression. what do I put in the Boolean expression

```
Console.Write("Enter Number 1: ", num1);
num1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

Console.Write("Enter Number 2: ", num2);
num2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

if (true)
{

}

switch (input)
{
    case 1:
        Console.WriteLine("\tResults: {0}", Add(num1, num2));
        break;
    case 2:
        Console.WriteLine("\tResults: {0}", Subtract(num1, num2));
        break;
    case 3:
        Console.WriteLine("\tResults: {0}", Multiply(num1, num2));
        break;
    case 4:
        Console.WriteLine("\tResults: {0}", Divide(num1, num2));
        break;
    default:

        //Console.WriteLine("Invalid Menu Selection.\t Try Again");
        //Console.ReadLine();
        return;
}

Console.WriteLine("Press any key...");
Console.ReadKey();
Console.Clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that the input is only numbers:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"^[-.]?[\d]{1,}[.]{0,1}[\d]{0,}$");
if(r.IsMatch(num1) && r.IsMatch(num2) && num1.Count(j => j == '.') < 2 && num2.Count(j => j == '.') < 2)
{
//Do something
}
```

And if both numbers are only nums, then use your switch statement.

If the input contains letters, then show some message to the user telling that only numbers are available

Comment: "-0.9" is valid input according to the question. Your code interprets as a wrong one.

Comment: Another issue: ".2" and "2." are valid inputs for C#. P.S: + is a shorthand for {1,} quantifier.

Comment: Nice one dude! ".2" and "2." fixed

Comment: Current regex allows 2.2.2 as a valid input :-)

Comment: One more issue: current regex allows "a3a" as a valid input

Comment: Try this one. I have tried and a3a not allowed, 2.2.2 not allowed.. :) Thanks for your help

Comment: Oscar, "-.2.2" is valid yet

Comment: ^^ edited! :) You are becoming my best friend right now!

Comment: I am sorry, but ".2.2" is valid yet.

Comment: Don´t be sorry! I am learning a lot trying to fix this haahha

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you can use [Double.TryParse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s27fasw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to check whether user input is a valid convertible to double string, as well as actually converting it (if the input is valid). For example :

```
double num1 = 0;
bool isNum1Valid = Double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out num1);
```

Actually, this question need more context, for example, how you want to use that function and it's signature (parameter type and return type). and showing what have you tried so far.

Comment: According to the question, "1e1" string is wrong. But your code interprets as a valid one.